# convert numpy conditional to regular python 2.7 syntax

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conditional-statements

I went onto one line of code, which I want to convert from numpy syntax to regular python 2.7 syntax:

```
SunAz=SunAz + (SunAz < 0) * 360
```

source:
https://github.com/Sandia-Labs/PVLIB_Python/blob/master/pvlib/pvl_ephemeris.py#L147

If we pretend that the numpy array is one dimensional, can it be translated to regular python 2.7 syntax like so:

```
newSunAz = []
for item in SunAz:
    if item < 0:
        newItem = item + item*360
        newSunAz.append(newItem)
    else:
        newSunAz.append(item)
```

??

Thank you for the help.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. It should work fine.

Comment: Are you just asking these questions to understand the effect of the numpy syntax?  I see you've asked three such questions now.  If your goal is simply to understand what numpy operations do, it might be better to ask one question with a few different examples, because as far as I can see, the three questions you've asked all have basically the same answer, which is "numpy operations work componentwise".

Comment: Thank you for the reply hagubear.
@BrenBarn - I am just afraid that I may not get an answer to all my questions if I ask all of them in one topic. I thought that separating them into a couple of individual ones, would disenable skipping replies to some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this would be the translation. The line

```
SunAz=SunAz + (SunAz < 0) * 360
```

`(SunAz < 0)` creates a boolean array, True where the angle is negative, and false otherwise. Multiplying `False` by a constant gives `0`, and `True` is interpreted to be a `1`. This line actually says, "shift the angle by 360 degrees if negative, otherwise leave it be".

So a more literal translation would be the following:

```
SunAz = [angle + 360 if angle < 0 else angle for angle in SunAz]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
new_sun_az = [i+360 if i > 0 else i for i in sun_az]
```

The main difference is that most operators are applied to the list object in plain Python lists and return a single result, while they return a numpy array where each item is the result of the operation applied to the corresponding item on the original array for numpy arrays.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> plainlist = range(5)
>>> plainlist
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> plainlist > 5   # single result
True
>>> nparray = np.array(plainlist)
>>> nparray
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> nparray > 5    # array of results
array([False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>>
```

[update]

Mike's answer is right. My original answer was:

```
new_sun_az = [i+i*360 if i > 0 else i for i in sun_az]
```